# Messed up my git repo, can't figure out how to sync properly

Tags: git, github

I added a file to `.gitignore` after (erroneously) trying to commit/push to github. It failed, because it was too large. I reset by `sudo git reset --hard a6563c9` (last entry before messing up, returned from `git log --oneline`).

That's all fine, but now it says my `branch is up to date with 'origin/master'`, which is not true (I've changed several otherr files).

I'm not sure how to get it to just re-scan all the files (except ones in .gitignore) in the repo for changes, so I can commit/push all my changes.

I've tried:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset .
```

as well as `git update-index --really-refresh`, `git update-index --no-skip-worktree`
(last one returns `Ignoring path`?)

Nothing I've tried changes the `branch is up to date with 'origin/master'` when trying to `git push`.

PS: I later found that I could supposedly have used

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git reset filename
```

and then added to .gitignore... But that's a bit late now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the message *branch is up to date with 'origin/master'*
because your local branch and remote branch point to the same commit. Your *git reset --hard a6563c9* did that.

You can restore your local master to its original commit by issuing another git reset command.  You need the commit-id of your original commit.  This can be found using git reflog. After that, you can modify your bad commit.

```
git checkout master
git reflog  #find id of your original erroneous commit
git reset --hard <id of original commit>
git reset --soft HEAD^
git reset <large file added by mistake>
git add .gitignore 
git commit
git push
```

I recommend always double checking the list of files you are committing.